# selenium webdriver call link with special character

Tags: java, selenium

i'm experimenting with selenium web-driver and would like to use something similar to the below code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http:\\awebsite.com?that%20has%20x");
```

unfortunately when i execute the code, in the browser appears:

```
http:\\awebsite.com?that has x
```

what do i need to do so that the %20 is not replaced by a "space"?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Many browsers show `%20` as a space but actually use the encoded version; are you sure this is not the case here? What happens when you copy the URL out of the address bar?

Comment: You can escape the `%` with a `%25`.  That would mean it would look like `%2520`...but I don't think that that is what you want.  What you are describing is standard browser behavior.

Comment: Thank you both for the fast reply! %25 works perfectly! thanks

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to use java's URLEncoder class.

For your example:

```
String q = "that%20has%20x";
String url = "http://google.com?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(q, "UTF-8");
driver.get(url);
```

In the browser address bar, you'll see:

```
https://www.google.com/?q=that%2520has%2520x
```

When the address is encoded, the '%' becomes '%25'.

[Here's a great Encoding Reference on www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

This has the same outcome as using @Nathan Merrill's suggestion.